# compiling log4cpp with custom toolchain

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, log4cpp

I am using log4cpp in our project. As we need to support various distributions of Linux, I have built a custom tool chain to build our project. Since my project is built with a custom tool chain, should I also build log4cpp with the same tool chain?

I can successfully build log4cpp using native compiler using the three simple commands as mentioned in it's web page.

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

But this library is not working with our custom built binary. I am new to Linux, So can't figure out the file to change for compiling with custom compiler. For example our custom tools are present in `/usr/custom/g++`.

Can I build a static library of log4cpp ans use in our project?
I am using Ubuntu 14.0 for compilation. Please help

Comment: There's a recipe for GNU autoconf stuff as well

Answer (score 0):

I just passed a parameter to the first command like the following

```
./configure CXX = /usr/custom/g++
```

When I run the make command, it automatically picked up the custom compiler and used it.